# Service Layer / Controller best practice in Zf2

Tags: architecture, zend-framework2

i need help by find any best practice for processing forms/inputfilters/hydrators.

If i have understood right

1.) service layer will handle, the data like

- hydrating
- filter/validate data
- handling (save, delete - CRUD)

2.) Controller will handle the glue between

- service layer
- form
- view
- etc.

Advantages:

- DRY principe
  you will be independent of output structure (json, rest, plain output etc.)
- form can be used blank, with this i mean, you can use the form without injected filters,    hydrators, they will be only injected if user sends data by for example an post request

but here i get my mistace, i dont know how to define the glue between

- service
- controller
- form

will i filter/validate data by service, or call the getter in controller to inject to the form?

i hope this would be understandable

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Service,** can be any objects that do some specific task which will be utilized by any models or codes in your entire application, the service can also be exposed through service configuration, ex. I had created a service to convert date of format dd/mm/yyyy to mysql and vice versa.

You asked can a filter/validator can be put inside as service, yes it's possible but you need N number of function to handle different form types, that deviates the core idea of service, for such purpose we can have models which can supply the filters required by the form

**Controllers** holds action which holds code which is glue to models and view, it's main purpose is routing to next stage of action(decision) based on the result from models. the main purpose of the controller is to control the flow of the application so it should have only few lines of codes as possible most of the action should be done only in the models, controllers only make calls to the methods in models and make a decision
Ex.

```
public function formAction(){
    /* @var $model \GlsApi\View\Models\ViewModelInterface */
    $model = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Entry/BoxInfoViewModel');
    $viewRenderModel = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('GlsApi/ViewRenderModel');
    $model->getFormView($viewRenderModel);
    return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(array('form' => $viewRenderModel->getRenderedView(), 'formValues' => $model->getDefaultValues()));
}

public function infoAction(){
    /* subscriber id or cardno */
    $id = $this->params()->fromPost("id", 0);
    $searchType = $this->params()->fromPost("st", 'subscriber');
    /* @var $model \GlsApi\Models\ModelInterface */
    $model = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Entry/BoxInfoViewModel');
    return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel($model->getInfo($id, $searchType)->getArrayCopy());
}
```

In the first action I am calling my view model using service locator, then call the getFormView method which set the partial that render the form and the form object to the view model passed and finally call the getRenderView method which create the form view all this are my custom methods which I had abstracted to ease my coding. I had build my RIA which transact using json that is that last line of my method.

**Form** this are class provided by ZF2 to represent a form as a data model which represent all html form elements along with Form objects we have validators and filters which reduce much of the form validation works

Hope this might give an idea, if need more clarification put specific queries  I will add more details